# e.preventDefault() not working despite $(document).on('click') reinstated after fullpage.js init

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js, preventdefault

I'm aware this is almost a duplicate of many questions here where the click handler has needed to be added back in following loading of dom elements which are created by another script, and with the usage of $(document).on('click', 'a') as opposed to $('a').click() - however my code is still not playing ball..

What I am trying to do is detect links within my code which contain certain values (href of sections in fullpage.js) and override the anchor and moveTo the section.

Strangely it is moving to the section fine - and I am able to override all links for test purposes so the preventDefault seems to be fine too, however having moved to the section it still triggers the anchor.

This function is triggered following init of fullpage.js so the event handler seems to be initialised in the correct place but still no luck.. any ideas!?

```
function overrideLinks() {

alert("overrideLinks");

//// Detect and overwrite page links from CMS to trigger fullpage nav
$("body").on('click', 'div.section a', function(e) {

    checkPath = $(this).attr('href');

    if (checkPath.indexOf("top-banner") >= 0) {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(1,0);

        e.preventDefault(); 

    }

});                         

}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `e.stopPropagation(); return false;` ?

Comment: I was under the impression that e.preventDefault() encompasses both stopPropagation and return false; - I've tried this anyway but with no luck unfortunately. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: `however having moved to the section it still triggers the anchor` What do you mean excactly?

Comment: I mean that the code is being triggered correctly by the event as demonstrated by the completion of  $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(1,0); - so the problem seems to lie within the preventDefault itself not working.

Comment: Move preventDefault outside of the if loop, does it work?

Comment: I guess your issue isn't related to your posted code. If you mean despite the fact you prevent default behaviour of anchor click but still after the plutgin animation (which is async), the page redirect as if the anchor default behaviour wasn't prevented, then your issue comes from somewhere else

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial there is no loop there

Comment: @A.Wolff if statement, you know what it means.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial ya i know... I guess you mean condition's block, not loop

Comment: Yeah I tested this with the preventDefault outside the if statement and still no luck. Even with e.preventDefault(); e.stopImmediatePropagation(); return false;

Comment: @chris.carruthers replicate issue somewhere it can be debugged. Again i think your issue comes from other code not posted

Comment: Yeah that is the conclusion I think I'm coming to as well - I'll run through everything else as there is a lot going on here in general so most likely a conflict of some kind. Many thanks for all your help! If I come up with anything solid I'll post the solution.

Comment: If anyone is interested in this I discovered the conflict was in fullPage.min.js options scrollOverflowOptions: { click: true, } by changing this to false and including additional code to respond to the click I managed to resolve it.

Comment: @chris.carruthers i wouldn't recommend you to play with those options. They will lead to undesirable results in mobile devices. Make sure to use the latest fullpage.js version 2.9.2. if you were not using it, that might be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, I think you're right and that the latest version at least in part resolved this, however it conflicted with something else on this tentative build so I had to roll back if I remember. This has done the trick though, it's solid enough.